# Do routers know what type of data they are handling?

Tags: router

I know that routers are used to send data between distinct networks, but am wondering if they recognize what type of data (i.e., image, emails) they are transmitting.

Comment: Just a thought: I heard that they are able to recognize FTP commands like "PASV/PORT" to get port numbers, so I would say yes, they may know the type of data, in some cases (but I'm curious about what would be the answers to this question though)

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, you might try this on serverfault.com.

Comment: @xav No, data type is different from service type.

Answer (score 2):

No, generally routers know service type instead of data type because of [well-known ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports). Routes focus on how to forward bytes between different networks, a problem like which path is better.

Let's take a look at tcp/ip protocol. Router is a device operates at the 3rd layer(internet). Only processes that work in application layer do care data type.

[image: tcp/ip protocol description quoted from wiki]

Comment: I am a server and I have a client that wants to start a connection with me. The client opens a TCP connection with my address and starts sending messages and I start sending responses. Everything is ok.

Now if I, the server, want to start a TCP connection with that client, the router protecting the client will stop me from even seeing the client. So no connection can be established by the server to the client.

Comment: Also, why does the router doesn't let me connect to the client, but allows my packages to pass when it was the client who started the connection?

Thanks.

Comment: @PedroD Your client must be in a private network. Please read the entry "NAT" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation and focus on the keywords "static NAT" and "static port mapping".